How to allow the User that has Viewer access in Google sheets be able to add and edit records in the Web App?
I want the user who has Viewer access in Google sheets be able to add and edit records in the Web App while maintaining my deployment settings like this:
Execute as: User accessing the web app
Who has access:  Anyone with Google account
They are able to access the Web App but whenever they're making changes in the records there, they are getting an error like "3622554558-mae_html_…tml_user__fil.js:64 Uncaught" and the changes are not applied. While the users who have Editor access in Google sheets can add and edit records in the Web App
Please help me with my codes to achieve my goal
Code.gs
function doGet(e) {
  return handleRequest(e);
}

function loadIndex(e) {
  return handleRequest(e);
}

function handleRequest(e) {
  // Check if the event object e is defined and has parameters
  var page = (e && e.parameter) ? e.parameter.page || 'index' : 'index'; // Default to 'index' if no page is specified or e is undefined

  try {
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    Logger.log("User Email from Session: " + userEmail); // Debugging line

    if (!userEmail) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Could not retrieve user email. Please ensure you are logged in.");
    }

    // Directly return the page since users are managed by Google Sheets permissions
    Logger.log("User is authorized: " + userEmail); // Debugging line
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
    
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log("Error in handleRequest: " + err.toString()); // Log the error
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("An error occurred: " + err.toString());
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}


This is impossible with a single pair of a web app and a spreadsheet.
For web apps that don't require Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() I think the most straightforward workaround is to change the deployment settings to "Run as me"; this way, the same web app will work for Editors and Viewers.
For web apps using methods like Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), it will be required to create two deployments, one for spreadsheet editors and another for spreadsheet viewers, or use the second deployment to handle the writing to the spreadsheet tasks.
Related

Google script: cannot refer to users using Session.getActiveUser()


I tried testing the web app with the user that has Viewer access in sheets with Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() and set it Execute as "Me" but it is not accessible and just getting the "Could not retrieve user email. Please ensure you are logged in."

Can I give write permission directly here in the code if the user has Viewer access? so they can modify the records. I'm sorry I am new to apps script and still figuring out how to implement the necessary requirements.

@Anonymous To give "write" permission, the code should run as you and should change the spreadsheet sharing permission / role for the user from viewer to editor. Please remember that comments are not intended to have extended discussion or make follow-up questions. To make a follow up question, post it as a new question.
